# Sample clip identification from a song

Tags: sample

Is there anywhere on the internet where I can have an audio sample used in a song identified? I'm referring to where the artist of a song chooses to borrow (read: sample) an audio clip from another source, e.g. putting a portion of a recorded speech in a musical track.

There are several audio clips that sound distinctly familiar to me, and I can't quite place where I've heard them before.

Comment: Well there's always Shazam for copyrighted commercial music but I fear it won't be of any assistance identifying creative commons or voice acting (eg audio books) tracks.

Comment: @DalvOlan The other issue with Shazam is that these samples are often very short and recorded inside a larger song, so Shazam will usually identify the song itself rather than the sample.

Comment: SoundHound has similar challenges, but may be a little better than Shazam for short samples.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether your answer is on [WhoSampled](http://www.whosampled.com/). The content is produced by humans and therefore not exhaustive, but it's worth a try.